# In python how to matching multiple strings and print results in table

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming

I am trying to write code to match words in a line and print the word i need from that line. like i have

```
Hostname router1
version 15
xxxx------
Hostname router2
version 14
xxxx------
```

I know there is problem in loop and correct library to use. Please can some one help me with it.
i want to extract `Hostname` and `version` in table

```
Hostname Version
router1    15
router2    14
```

Note: i need some help in using correct lib for matching/extracting data in a line.
my code is :

```
import re
from prettytable import PrettyTable
with open('testfile.txt','r') as input:
    table = PrettyTable(['Hostname', 'Version'])
    space = ''
    cntr = 1
    for line in input.read().split('\n'):
    match1=re.match(r'Hostname(.*)''|''version(.*)',line,
    re.MULTILINE)
       if match1:
          space = ''
          cntr += 1
          str= (match1.group())

          table.add_row([match1.group(1),match1.group(2)])
          print(table)
       else:
          cntr+=1
          space=space+'\n'+line
```

Comment: Is below ansrwer is satisying your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#sample.txt contains following data:

Hostname router1
version 15
xxxx------
Hostname router2
version 14
xxxx------
```

---

```
#Code:

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sample.txt", sep=" " , names=["Host", "Version"])
# print df
print type(df)
for item in zip(df["Host"], df["Version"]):
    if "Hostname" in item[0] or "version" in item[0]:
        print(item[0] +  " : " + str(item[1]))
```

---

```
#output:
Hostname : router1
version : 15
Hostname : router2
version : 14
```

Comment: @venkat for what reason you want reason in tabular form?Do you want to put this output in any file?

Comment: yes i want it be in csv format. the main goal of this concept is to create a  code that match's/search from text file and make it in csv file in each column with Header.  Thank you for interest on this. Let me know if you need more info like my reference code i made to convert from text file to csv.

Comment: Hi any luck on it

Comment: Will get back to you tomorrow